# Is there any way to compare normal linux latency with RTAI linux latency test?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, real-time, rtai

Please anyone have any idea or source code for latency test for normal linux & rtai linux?
I want to do performance testing comparison(how much improve after rtai installation).

Please guide me for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RTAI's latency test located in under `install_dir/testsuite/kern/latency` or `install_dir/testsuite/user/latency`. For further information check Section 4.7 of [RTAI's User Manual](https://www.rtai.org/userfiles/documentation/documents/RTAI_User_Manual.pdf).

Comment: I know how to run latency test For RTAI but i want to compare with normal linux latency test.

Comment: I don't really get the point of doing that - "Normal" Linux latency can be anything - From 0 to "some time next year" - There is no guarantee whatsoever that what you'd be measuring on a test system could be reproduced on any other system under real-live load, or even on the same system the next day....